# UICollectionView Data Source methods inside of UITabBarView not being called until tab is navigated to

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionview

I have an issue that I can reproduce.  I can see what the issue is but for the life of me I cant figure out how to correct it.  FIrst, let me explain the view structure.

The root View Controller for the window is a TabBarController.  TabBarController contains two views, NavigationController 1 (nav) with its root view contrller set as a UITableView and NavigationController 2(nav2) with its root view controller set to a UICollectionView.  Here is how that is all setup in the AppDelegate:

```
 WTATableView *tv = [[WTATableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WTATableView" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
 initWithRootViewController:tv];
 nav.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Birthday List", nil);
 nav.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"birthdaycake"];


WTACollectionViewController *cv = [[WTACollectionViewController alloc] 
initWithCollectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]];


UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]    
initWithRootViewController:cv];
nav2.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Birthday Grid", nil);
nav2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"package"];

UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabController.viewControllers = @[nav, nav2];
self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

The CollectionView subscribes to a notification that is posted by an entry view controller and takes the data returned in the notification UserInfo dictionary and updates the UICollectionview by calling the data source methods.  Here is that code:

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification

{
   [self.birthdays addObject:[notification userInfo]];

 NSLog(@"Calling handle method");

if([self.birthdays count] == 1){
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
if (self.birthdays.count > 1) {
     NSLog(@" Number of itmes in section B: %d", [self.collectionView 
numberOfItemsInSection:0]);        [self.collectionView    
insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:   (self.birthdays.count -1) 
inSection:0]]];
}


}
```

So on the first Tab Bar item that contains nav with its root controller set as a UITableView, if I tap the NavBarButton to show the modal view controller and get the user entry and then dismiss the modal controller to return to the UITableVIew, I get the new table entry.  If I then tap on the tab Bar item that contains nav2 with its root controller as the UICollectionView and then back to the UITable tab bar item, I can continue to add as many entries as I want, no problems.  BUT, if I dont navigate to that tab bar item containing the uicollectionview and try to add a second entry from the uitableview, I get a crash every single time, Invalid number of items in section".

I can see that if I dont navigate to the uicontroller tab, the data source methods for the uicontroller are never called.  It is like the UICollectionView is not being initialized until I navigate to the tab bar but I know it is because I NSLog out the init methods and view did load methods when the app first starts up.  I thought this might have something to do with uicollectionview being wrapped in the nav2 controller so I took that away and I ge the exact same behavior...  I feel like I am missing something here that is causing me a lot of grief...  ANy suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can clearly see that when the birthdays array has one item and that condition is met in the handleNotification method that the datasource methods numberofItemsinSection and cellforItemAtIndexPath ARE NOT being called. EVEN though I can see that the instance is the collectionview datasource and delegate at that time by doing an NSLog of [self.collectionview.datasource].  That gives me the same instance as I log out in the uicollectionview viewdidload method using NSLog of self.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get this to work.  It feels "hacky" but it works :-)  I had to simulate a tab bar navigation event in code.  SO in the handler method outlined above, in the condition that birthdays == 1 I added self.TabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;  Then, in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, just before returning a cell, I inserted self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;  I still wish I knew the root cause, what exactly flipping to and from the uicollectionview tabb ar really does.....